# webpack src files changes are not reflecting, not showing the path

Tags: webpack, sass

I am using webpack for sass integration, webpack is compiling to sass but I do changes in the src folder but nothing has been reflected or any changes is shown. Could any one help me out. Webpack is running on // ./src/css/main.scss  like webpack:///src/css/main.scss

src/css/Main.scss

```
/**
 * Main Style Entry Point
 */

@import '00-vendors/_vendors';
@import '01-settings/_settings';
@import '02-tools/_tools';
@import '03-generic/_generic';
@import '04-layout/_layout';
@import '05-components/_components';
@import '06-views/_views';
@import '07-cat/_category';
```

I do changes the code but it didnot reflect reflects any changes[image]

Comment: Repacking and rebuilding the bundle solves the problem